# Using a service in Jhipster to populate a second entity with user uploaded CSV BLOB entity

Tags: mysql, spring, csv, jhipster

I am new to Jhipster and trying to create a basic app that will allow a user to upload a CSV file and then view the contents in an entity.

I am trying to figure out a way to populate a second entity with the data contained in a CSV blob that will be uploaded by the user. I have created an entity that allows the user to upload a CSV file and store it in the database as a BLOB, and I have also created a service with the intention of populating a second entity with records based on the contents of the CSV file that was uploaded.

How would I go about this? I have used OpenCSV in the past to read CSV files and populate MySQL tables via their filepath, but I am unfamiliar with accessing CSV files that are stored in the database as a BLOB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented same use case using supercsv but I don't store the csv in blob: in service I parse the DTO from controller and stores resulting entities, in the blob I store the errors if any. It's a bit abusive but it works well and the entity to create the other one is just a way to record how upload went, this way I can reuse the UI generated by JHipster without any change.

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your code for the entity and the service?

Comment: No it's not open source but there's nothing complex: just generate the entity for the import using DTO option and binary type field, this way it's easier to isolate the CSV parsing in service without impacting the entity and repository.

Answer (score 0):

1.in html:

```
                </td>
                <td style="padding: 5px;">
                    <input type="button"
                           name="Reset"
                           id="txtFileReset"
                           class="btn btn-primary"
                           (click)="csvReset()"
                           value="Reset"/>
                    <input type="button"
                           name="Reset"
                           id="txtFileSave"
                           class="btn btn-primary"
                           (click)="csvSave()"
                           value="Save CSV To DB"/>
                </td>
```

2.in ts:

```
        csvRecords = [];

        fileChangeListener($event): void {
        const text = [];
        const target = $event.target || $event.srcElement;
        const files = target.files;

    if (Constants.validateHeaderAndRecordLengthFlag) {
        if (!this.fileUtil.isCSVFile(files[0])) {
            alert('Please import valid .csv file.');
            this.csvReset();
        }
    }

    const input = $event.target;
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);

    reader.onload = data => {
        const csvData = reader.result;
        const csvRecordsArray = csvData.split(/\r\n|\n/);

        let headerLength = -1;
        if (Constants.isHeaderPresentFlag) {
            const headersRow = this.fileUtil.getHeaderArray(csvRecordsArray, Constants.tokenDelimeter);
            headerLength = headersRow.length;
        }

        this.csvRecords = this.fileUtil.getDataRecordsArrayFromCSVFile(
            csvRecordsArray,
            headerLength,
            Constants.validateHeaderAndRecordLengthFlag,
            Constants.tokenDelimeter
        );

        if (this.csvRecords === null) {
            // If control reached here it means csv file contains error, reset file.
            this.csvReset();
        }
    };

    reader.onerror = function() {
        alert('Unable to read ' + input.files[0]);
    };
}

csvReset() {
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#txtFileUpload').value = '';
    this.csvRecords = [];
}
csvSave() {
    this.ipInfo = new IpInfoSdmSuffix();
    for (let i = 1; i < this.csvRecords.length; i++) {
        this.ipInfo.name = this.csvRecords[i][0];
        this.ipInfo.addressStart = this.csvRecords[i][1];
        this.ipInfo.addressEnd = this.csvRecords[i][2];
        this.ipInfo.validType = this.csvRecords[i][3];
        this.subscribeToSaveResponse(this.ipInfoService.create(this.ipInfo));
    }
}

private subscribeToSaveResponse(result: Observable<HttpResponse<IIpInfoSdmSuffix>>) {
    result.subscribe((res: HttpResponse<IIpInfoSdmSuffix>) => this.onSaveSuccess(), (res: HttpErrorResponse) => this.onSaveError());
}

private onSaveSuccess() {
    this.isSaving = false;
    this.isCsvSaved = false;
    // this.previousState();
    this.clear();
}
private onSaveError() {
    this.isSaving = false;
    this.isCsvSaved = false;
}
```